# ionic meteor app production build failing

Tags: android, typescript, meteor, ionic-framework, webpack

project is working fine in development, but while trying to build for platform (android), errors are occurring.

Notes:

- meteor framework is being used
- client is ionic
- angular version is 4
- webpack is being used as the module build

**command** `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` **returning below error;**

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'api/collections' in '/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/pages/user/user-profile-edit'
resolve 'api/collections' in '/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/pages/user/user-profile-edit'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/user/user-profile-edit)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/package.json (relative path: ./src/pages/user/user-profile-edit)
    resolve as module
      /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/pages/user/user-profile-edit/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/pages/user/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/pages/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/noshu/code/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/noshu/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules
        using description file: /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/api/collections)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules/api/collections doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules/api/collections.js doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules/api/collections.ts doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules/api/collections doesn't exist
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/pages/user/user-profile-edit/node_modules]
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/pages/user/node_modules]
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/pages/node_modules]
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/src/node_modules]
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/node_modules]
[/home/noshu/code/node_modules]
[/home/noshu/node_modules]
[/home/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules/api/collections]
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules/api/collections.js]
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules/api/collections.ts]
[/home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules/api/collections]
 @ ./src/pages/user/user-profile-edit/user-profile-edit.page.js 5:20-46
 @ ./src/app/app.module.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
```

below is the folder structure;

[image: project]

[image: api]

[image: src]

webpack.config.js;

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ionicWebpackFactory = require(process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_FACTORY);

module.exports = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: process.env.IONIC_OUTPUT_JS_FILE_NAME,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [
      // /home/noshu/code/ptc-gps/nexxdeli-mobile/node_modules
      path.resolve('node_modules')
    ],
    alias: {
      'api': path.resolve(__dirname, 'api/server')
    }
  },

  externals: [
    resolveExternals
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_TRANSPILE_LOADER
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      __extends: 'typescript-extends'
    })
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    __dirname: true
  }
};

function resolveExternals(context, request, callback) {
  return resolveMeteor(request, callback) ||
    callback();
}

function resolveMeteor(request, callback) {
  var match = request.match(/^meteor\/(.+)$/);
  var pack = match && match[1];

  if (pack) {
    callback(null, 'Package["' + pack + '"]');
    return true;
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json;

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "api/*": ["./api/server/*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "types": [
      /*"@types/underscore"*/
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "api/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "api/node_modules",
    "api"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

package.json;

```
{
    "name": "Nexxdeli-App",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "MRHASAN/ptc-gps.de",
    "homepage": "http://ptc-gps.de",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "meteor-client:bundle": "meteor-client bundle -s api -c meteor-client.config.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
        "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "^1.0.0",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.95.0",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.7",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
        "cordova-plugin-fcm": "^2.1.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
        "ionic-angular": "3.5.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.11",
        "meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.7",
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.1",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
        "@types/meteor": "^1.4.2",
        "@types/underscore": "^1.8.1",
        "ionic": "3.7.0",
        "meteor-typings": "^1.4.1",
        "tmp": "0.0.31",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
        "typescript": "2.3.4",
        "typescript-extends": "^1.0.1"
    },
    "description": "Nexxdeli Ionic project",
    "config": {
        "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js"
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-fcm": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic-CLI wants all the imports to be located inside the `src` directory. So to fix the `--prod` build you simply need to move the `api` directory inside the `src` directory.
Here you can find a small example where `ionic cordova run android --prod` works for production builds:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QRo0PQLXYCRG6nc-nO6lECzjya-8oMLk

More info here:
https://github.com/Urigo/Ionic2CLI-Meteor-WhatsApp/issues/113#issuecomment-342187908